# Configuring PXE boot with separate DHCP server

Tags: boot, uefi, dhcp, pxe

I'm trying to configure a PXE boot server, but the DHCP is on a separate machine.
I have 2 WDS servers already running, and they can be chosen in the boot menu. But this freshly configured Linux machine doesn't show up.

I combined various guides and read up on the docs

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/netboot-amd64

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/netbooting-the-live-server-installer/14510

Any suggestions to how I can make this work are appreciated

/etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=eth0,lo
bind-interfaces


#----------------------#
# Specify TFTP Options #
#----------------------#

#--location of the pxeboot file
dhcp-boot=bios/pxelinux.0

#--enable tftp service
enable-tftp

#-- Root folder for tftp
tftp-root=/tftp

#--Detect architecture and send the correct bootloader file
dhcp-match=set:efi-x86_64,option:client-arch,7 
dhcp-boot=tag:efi-x86_64,grub/bootx64.efi
```

/tftp/bios/pxelinux.cfg/default

```
    DEFAULT menu.c32
    MENU TITLE PXE SERVER 1.0
    PROMPT 0 
    TIMEOUT 0

    MENU COLOR TABMSG  37;40  #ffffffff #00000000
    MENU COLOR TITLE   37;40  #ffffffff #00000000 
    MENU COLOR SEL      7     #ffffffff #00000000
    MENU COLOR UNSEL    37;40 #ffffffff #00000000
    MENU COLOR BORDER   37;40 #ffffffff #00000000

    LABEL Ubuntu Custom ISO
        kernel /boot/casper/vmlinuz
        append nfsroot=10.119.16.53:/var/www/html/ubuntu/desktop/ netboot=nfs ro file=/media/iso/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=boot/casper/initrd.lz ip=dhcp systemd.mask=tmp.mount --
```

ll /tftp/*

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1492864 Mar  8 11:53 /tftp/grubx64.efi

/tftp/bios:
total 9544
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root      4096 Mar  8 11:33 ./
drwxr-xr-x  5 root   root      4096 Mar  8 11:53 ../
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root        10 Mar  8 11:32 boot -> /tftp/boot/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    122656 Mar  8 11:31 ldlinux.c32*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root     23700 Mar  8 11:31 libutil.c32*
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     91044 Mar  8 11:32 lpxelinux.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root     26568 Mar  8 11:31 menu.c32*
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     46995 Mar  8 11:32 pxelinux.0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root      4096 Mar 11 09:01 pxelinux.cfg/
drwxrwxr-x 32   1026   1026    4096 Mar  4  2016 syslinux-6.04-pre1/
-rw-rw-r--  1 ibtest ibtest 9406628 Mar  8 11:29 syslinux-6.04-pre1.tar.gz
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root     27020 Mar  8 11:32 vesamenu.c32*

/tftp/boot:
total 932
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   4096 Mar  8 11:51 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   4096 Mar  8 11:53 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Mar  8 11:45 casper/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 May 20  2021 grub/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 482356 May 20  2021 grub-efi-amd64-signed_1.167.2+2.04-1ubuntu44.2_amd64.deb
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   4096 Aug 13  2021 shim/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 447804 Aug 13  2021 shim-signed_1.40.7+15.4-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb

/tftp/grub:
total 956
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Mar  9 16:33 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   4096 Mar  8 11:53 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 955656 Mar  8 11:54 bootx64.efi
-r--r--r-- 1 root root   5004 Mar  8 11:55 font.pf2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    967 Mar  9 16:33 grub.cfg
```